# I have the data source(com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData) how can I get the state of the document?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a handle to the data source, that I know belongs to a document.

The document can be a new document.

I need to know the state: Is it new, open or edit?

Basically I wish to hide/show a button in a custom control, based on the state of the document this custom control is in. The custom control it self has other data sources, so I can't use currentDocument - because this will reflect the data source in the custom control.

If there's a simpler way to solve this problem I'm all ears!

Running on a Domino 8.5.3 FP3 server.

Hope this is clear.

Thanks!

/J

Comment: a document itself can't be in read or edit mode. Your data sources can. So you check the document for isNewNote and the data source for read/edit.  The approach with custom properties as Felix suggest is usual practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can realize this with property definition for the custom control

1. add 2 property definitions to the custom control

   - Name = newmode
   - Type = boolean
   - Name = editmode
   - Type = boolean
2. change the rendered property of the buttons

   if (compositeData.editmode==true) {
    false
    }
    else {true}

or

if (compositeData.newmode==true) { false } else {true}

3. go to the XPages which has the custom control as member an map the status of the datasoucre to the customcontrol property definitions

[image]

I think the status open is always valid, just when the Xpages is open...

Comment: Ah! TOO easy! =)

Thanks!